# Overriding pending transition in android

Tags: android

I have two activities.. Activity A and Activity B.

When I start Activity B from Activity A. I want Activity A to be static to its positions and animations to show up only for Activity B. How do i achieve this using overridingPendingTransition?

This below code is called from ActivityA when button is clicked as follows :

**Activity A:**

```
public void onClick(View v) {
        super.onClick(v);
         if (v.getId() == R.id.button) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), MyProfileActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up, R.anim.slide_out_up);
        }
```

Activity A also slides with Activity B.
How to stop the animation of Activity A and enable animations of Activity B alone?

**slide_out_up xml is as follows :**

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="0%"
        android:toYDelta="-100%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromAlpha="1"
        android:toAlpha="0" />

</set>
```

**slide_in_up :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <translate
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:toYDelta="0%" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />

</set>
```

Comment: You probably can create a fake animation for the out animation (from 100% x to 100% x for instance) to achieve this. I haven't tried it though so not sure it would work but give it a go.

Comment: Show your `slide_in_up.xml` and `slide_out_up.xml` file

Comment: You can see this example in [GmailAnimation](https://github.com/CabezasGonzalezJavier/GmailAnimation). Also see more in this [blog](http://thedeveloperworldisyours.com/android/gmail-overriding-pending-transition/#sthash.CEhJwJLg.dpbs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The simplest way you could go is pass 0 for the second parameter, instead of R.anim.slide_out_up. However, this usually leads to Activity A showing up as a black screen behind Activity B, so as a workaround you can provide any animation that does nothing - e.g. translation from 0% to 0%.

Comment: Egor.. you are right!! Activity A is shown as black screen. But Activity A should be visible for users. Any idea of how to go about it?

Comment: overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_up,R.anim.scale_to_center);

Answer (score 1):

Need to use this.

`slide_in_left.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXDelta="-100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

`slide_in_right.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false" >

<translate
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXDelta="100%"
    android:toXDelta="0%" />

<alpha
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />

</set>
```

Comment: Piyush.. These xmls slides the screens either left/right. But i need bottom to top animation itself keeping the activity behind and visible.

Comment: @shalini You can do one thing for this.

Comment: Exactly..Show Activity A as it is and animate Activity B from bottom to top

Comment: @shalini You have to open your second activity as a Dialog activity with animation so it will keep your Activity A to static position and you can animate only Activity B without affecting to Activity A.